# How to make a custom async progress method?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I'm trying to make an `async` function (I'm not very good with `async` in general!) and lets say I want it to do this:

```
async public string Count()
{
    int x = 0;

    for(x; x<100000; x++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }

    return "I'm done";
}
```

I would like to catch that "x" and store it somewhere else, or bind it to a textbox representing progress eg. `"x / 100000"`

How can I do that?

Comment: I would suggest that you fire an event each time and bubble the event up to the UI. [Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8627sbea.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an object of [Progress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) class and pass it to the `Count()` method. The Progress class has an event handler which can be called every time the async task has some progress to report. The progress is reported by the [OnReport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159267(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
var progress = new Progress<int>(); // define your own type or use a builtin type 
progress += (counter) => { //This will be called each time the async func calls Report. 
                          //counter will have the reported value 
                          }


  await Count(progress);
```

Inside the `Count` function

```
async public string Count(Progress<int> progress)
{
 int x = 0;

    for(x; x<100000; x++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        progress.OnReport(x);
    }

    return "I'm done";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. In the meantime I've actually stumbled upon `Progress` and got my code to work, however as your reply is exactly what I was asking about and you gave such a simple and understandable answer, I just have to mark it as one :) Thank you! :)